Reverse order of rows (or columns) in a tikzcd diagram, by passing an option/style argument?
Is it possible to define an option which, when passed to a tikzcd diagram, will reverse the order of the rows (or columns) in the diagram?  That is, I’d like to write something like
\begin{tikzcd}[reversecolumns] A & B & C \end{tikzcd}

and get an output equivalent to
\begin{tikzcd} C & B & A \end{tikzcd}

and similarly with an option reverserows for rows.  For comparison, in a TikZ diagram with manually-positioned nodes, one can flip the diagram by changing its co-ordinates to negative values — but I can’t see how to do anything similar for a tikzcd diagram, since it’s given as a matrix.
The use-case is that I have some large tikzcd diagrams, and I want to experiment with reversing their orientation, to see which versions look better (and I’ve had this situation several times in the past); but manually reversing the rows/columns of a matrix in the source is slow and error-prone.  I guess any solution would probably work for general TikZ matrices, not just tikzcd, but the tikzcd case would be sufficient for me.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (0,0) {$A$}; \node (B) at (1,0) {$B$}; \node (C) at (2,0) {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(-1,0)}]
  \node (A) at (0,0) {$A$}; \node (B) at (1,0) {$B$}; \node (C) at (2,0) {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzcd} A & B & C \end{tikzcd}

% desired syntax:
% \begin{tikzcd}[reversecolumns] A & B & C \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}


Would flipping the digram horizontally be sufficient to get an idea how it will look like in reverse?

This is basically the same question as Q507285 which asks the same for the other dimension (last row should be first). But the OP also answers it for the other dimension. Simply: Choose a negative column sep/row sep. It's not perfect but it's certainly the easiest and quickest solution. (It doesn't fully makes sure that the spaces between the rows/column is greather than the absolute value of the chosen negative length, I think.) The key that can be made a bit smart so that it works with the same options as TikZ-CD's sep key (large, small, …).

Background: a TikZ matrix is more similar to a tabular table. This makes it less versatile but easy to use for alignment. You can't simply reverse the columns (or rows) with a tabular either. (Though, the same trick could be used.)
